# ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient for windows 10

Tags: mysql

```
C:\Users\Akshay\PycharmProjects>pip install mysqlclient
    Collecting mysqlclient
      Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
      Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x_id5m86'
    cwd: C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hhw69sra\mysqlclient\
      Complete output (23 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
      Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
    Failed to build mysqlclient
    Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
        Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kh5vz2_g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient'
             cwd: C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hhw69sra\mysqlclient\
        Complete output (23 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-3.8
        creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
        creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
        running build_ext
        building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hhw69sra\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kh5vz2_g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider formatting your post.  As it is, it's difficult to read.  Also, please point out how you're installing it.  IIRC, you need VS to build the mysqlclient in Windows.

Comment: re: somewhere like https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ if you don't have VS setup.  Do note, it's a 3rd party website.  while I've used the files there, ymmv.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft C++ Build tool required to install fabric - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006346/microsoft-c-build-tool-required-to-install-fabric-python)

Comment: So does it mean i have to download the entire VS setup or just the build tools?

Comment: So does it mean i have to download the entire VS setup or just the build tools?

Comment: now even after installing the VS build tool